# AppStore update app

Tags: ios, app-store, release

I've faced the issue. Yesterday I received approve from AppStore team and submitted the app to store and now I have status 'Ready for Sale' for more than 20 hours, but I don't see this app version in AppStore. 
Is it okay or something went wrong?
Which support section should I use in this case?

Comment: Are you asking that : "Why your app is not coming in app store search?"

Comment: @AshishKakkad No, I can't see it on App Store page too when I click on 'View on App Store' button in Additional Information section in appstoreconnect

Comment: When you click on View on App Store, What happens?

Comment: @AshishKakkad It goes straight to my app page, but previous version.

Comment: Oh ok. You already have previous version. It will take some time to reflect new version on app store. I think it will take around 24 hours.

Comment: @AshishKakkad Thanks, I'll be w8 it :)

Comment: I also have such a problem :(

Comment: I've the same problem also from around 21 hours ago it got "Ready for Sale" , and till now update is not showing on AppStore .. Also tried changing price and territory availability but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

It can take some time for your new version to appear in the App Store sometimes up to 24 hours or more.